# Website not updating when hosted on bluehost

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a simple website that displayed data from a mysql database in a table. I can edit data or input new data to the sql and it displays on the page. All works perfectly on XAMPP and I finished the website.

I then uploaded the website to bluehost but now whenever I add new data or edit existing data the page does not update. No matter how many times I refresh the site the website does not update. If I load a new browser or incognito tab then the new data appears.

I've pasted my code below - is that the issue or is it bluehost?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>BGA Tracking</title>

</head>


<?php include('header.php'); ?>

<div class="topnav">
  <a href="index.php">Tracking</a>
  <a href="vendors.php">Vendors</a>
</div>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<BR>

<center>


<button class="button-air" id="myBtn">Add shipment</button>
</center>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="add_PDO.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data";">
    <table class="styled-table">        
        <tr class="active-row">
            <td><label for="inputPassword">Date</label></td>
            <td> <input type="date" name="shipping_date" required ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="active-row">
            <td><label for="freight-select">Freight</label></td>
            <td><select name="freight" id="freight-select" required>
    <option value="">--Please select an option--</option>
    <option value="British">British</option>
    <option value="Delta">Delta</option>
    <option value="American">American</option>
    <option value="Air Canada">Air Canada</option>
    <option value="Cargojet">Cargojet</option>
    <option value="Amerijet">Amerijet</option>
    <option>----</option>
    <option value="Fedex">Fedex</option>
    <option value="DHL">DHL</option>
    <option value="IBC">IBC/UPS</option>
    <option>----</option>
    <option value="Sea">Sea</option>
</select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="active-row">
            <td><label for="inputPassword">Receiver Number</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="receiver" required </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="active-row">
            <td><label for="inputPassword">AWB</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="tracking_no" </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="active-row">
            <td><label for="inputPassword">Pieces (optional)</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="pieces"</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="active-row">
            <td><label class="control1" for="inputPassword">Comments</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="comments" </td>
        </tr>



</table>
        <center>
         <button type="submit" name="update" style="center" class="btn btn-success";">Add Shipment</button><br><br>
        </center>

</form>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>


<table class="styled-table">
<tr class="active-row"><th colspan="10"><center>Air Cargo</center></TH></tr>
<tr class="active-row">
<th width="20px">Arrival date</th>
<th width="40px">Flight</th>
<th width="80px">AWB</th>
<th width="80px">Vendor</th>
<th width="50px">Receiver</th>
<th width="30px">Pieces</th>
<th width="20px">DIT</th>
<th width="80px">Status</th>
<th width="300px">Comments</th>
<th width="80px"></TH>
</tr>
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "123");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM final_view WHERE freight IN ('British', 'Delta', 'American', 'Cargojet', 'Amerijet', 'Air Canada' ) and completed IS NULL ORDER BY shipping_date DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["shipping_date"] . "</td><td>" . $row["freight"]. "</td><td>" . $row["tracking_no"] . "</td><td>" . $row["vendor_name"] . "</td><td>" . $row["receiver"] . "</td><td>" . $row["pieces"] . "</td>
<td>" . $row["days_in_transit"] . "</td><td>" . $row["air_status"] . "</td><td>" . $row["comments"] . "</td><td align=right><a href='air_edit.php?id=".$row['id']."' class='button-edit1'>Edit</a>&nbsp
<a href='complete.php?id=".$row['id']."' class='button-complete'>Complete</a></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else { echo "0 results"; }
$conn->close();
?>

</table>
<BR>


<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->


<table class="styled-table">
<tr class="active-row"><th colspan="10"><center>Fedex / DHL / IBC / UPS</center></TH></tr>
<tr class="active-row">
<th width="20px">Ship date</th>
<th width="20px">Courier</th>
<th width="50px">AWB</th>
<th width="80px">Vendor</th>
<th width="50px">Receiver</th>
<th width="30px">Pieces</th>
<th width="20px">DIT</th>
<th width="80px">Status</th>
<th width="300px">Comments</th>
<th width="80px"></TH>
</tr>
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "123");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM final_view WHERE freight = 'Fedex' OR freight = 'DHL' OR freight = 'IBC' and completed IS NULL ORDER BY shipping_date DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["shipping_date"] . "</td><td>" . $row["freight"]. "</td><td>" . $row["tracking_no"] . "</td><td>" . $row["vendor_name"] . "</td><td>" . $row["receiver"] . "</td><td>" . $row["pieces"] . "</td>
<td>" . $row["days_in_transit"] . "</td><td>" . $row["courier_status"] . "</td><td>" . $row["comments"] . "</td><td align=right><a href='courier_edit.php?id=".$row['id']."' class='button-edit1'>Edit</a>&nbsp
<a href='complete.php?id=".$row['id']."' class='button-complete'>Complete</a></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else { echo "0 results"; }
$conn->close();
?>
</table>

<BR>

<center>
<table class="styled-table">
<tr class="active-row"><th colspan="9"><center>Sea Freight</center></TH></tr>
<tr class="active-row">
<th width="20px">Ship date</th>
<th width="100px">Vendor</th>
<th width="80px">Receiver</th>
<th width="50px">Pieces</th>
<th width="20px">BoL</th>
<th width="50px">DIT</th>
<th width="150px">Status</th>
<th width="300px">Comments</th>
<th width="80px"></TH>
</tr>
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "123");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM final_view WHERE freight = 'Sea' and completed IS NULL ORDER BY shipping_date DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["shipping_date"] . "</td><td>" . $row["vendor_name"] . "</td><td>" . $row["receiver"] . "</td><td>" . $row["pieces"] . "</td><td>" . $row["bol"] . "</td>
<td>" . $row["days_in_transit"] . "</td><td>" . $row["sea_status"] . "</td><td>" . $row["comments"] . "</td>
<td align=right><a href='sea_edit.php?id=".$row['id']."' class='button-edit1'>Edit</a>&nbsp<a href='complete.php?id=".$row['id']."' class='button-complete'>Complete</a></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else { echo "0 results"; }
$conn->close();
?>
</table>
<BR>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->

<center>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit - And below is my header.php

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s",time()+(-1*60))." GMT");

<style>


.center {
width: 90%;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 25px;
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
}

.styled-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 25px 0;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 70%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}

.styled-table thead tr {
    background-color: #009879;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}

.styled-table th,
.styled-table td {
    padding: 8px 10px;
}

.styled-table tbody tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.styled-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.styled-table tbody tr:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #009879;
}

.styled-table tbody tr.active-row {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #009879;
    text-align: left;
}

.active-row1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #009879;
    text-align: center;
}


/* The Modal (background) */
        .modal {
            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
            padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%; /* Full width */
            height: 100%; /* Full height */
            overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }

        /* Modal Content */
        .modal-content {
            background-color: #fefefe;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            width: 60%;
        }

        /* The Close Button */
        .close {
            color: #aaaaaa;
            float: right;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .close:hover,
        .close:focus {
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        

.button1 {
  background-color: #1ef43e;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-family: sans-serif;

  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.button-edit {
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #9fb4f2;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #7892c2 5%, #476e9e 100%);
    background-color:#7892c2;
    border-radius:3px;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px 9px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #283966;
}
.button-edit:hover {
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #476e9e 5%, #7892c2 100%);
    background-color:#476e9e;
}
.button-edit:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}


.button-complete {
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #a4e271;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #89c403 5%, #77a809 100%);
    background-color:#89c403;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #74b807;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:4px 3px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #528009;
}
.button-complete:hover {
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #77a809 5%, #89c403 100%);
    background-color:#77a809;
}
.button-complete:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

.button-edit1 {
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #276873;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #599bb3 5%, #408c99 100%);
    background-color:#599bb3;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #29668f;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:4px 5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #3d768a;
}
.button-edit1:hover {
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #408c99 5%, #599bb3 100%);
    background-color:#408c99;
}
.button-edit1:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

.button-air {
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100%);
    background-color:#ededed;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#009879;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}
.button-air:hover {
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100%);
    background-color:#dfdfdf;
}
.button-air:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

label,
footer {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

label {
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

select {
    font-size: .9rem;
    padding: 2px 5px;
}

footer {
    font-size: .8rem;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 30px;
}  




/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #009879;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}




</style>
```

Comment: This is probably a caching mecanism enabled you cannot control if you're using a shared hosting system. If the changes appear incognito it should also appear if you press ctrl+alt+r while on the website or delete your browser cache.

Comment: The changes appear when I load a new incognito page and type the url. But then the same issue happens, a refresh will not work if i add more data.

Comment: https://themeskills.com/turn-off-server-caching-bluehost/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is in your *header.php* file? Try adding to it the following (and it must have a `<?php` directive:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s",time()+(-1*60))." GMT");
?>
```

I use BlueHost and the above is a platform-independent method that should work.

**Update**

The header must go out before the HTML! Move the include for the header:

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>BGA Tracking</title>
etc.
```

Comment: Hi - I added your code but still the same result sadly. I've edited my oringal post to include the header.php

Comment: Hi, I moved the include line as directed but now your code just appears as text at the top of the page. My header is above in the main post. I then moved your code inside the style tag but that hasn't resolved it - still the same issue. Am I using your code in the correct place in the header.php?

Comment: See my updated answer. You need to have a `<?php` directive in your *header.php* file surrounding the `header` statements.

Comment: Thank you so much - that has fixed the issue. Just as side note to all this, out of my frustration getting this to work I also signed up a2hosting to see if the same problem exists - it did not. on a2hosting the website worked right away and updated perfectly. With bluehost I have to add your code to get it working properly.